# What is the license of the code posted on the site?

Tags: discussion

I find this amazing small piece of code in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24636/53092):

```
datediff() {
   d1=$(date -d "$1" +%s)
   d2=$(date -d "$2" +%s)
   echo $(( (d1 - d2) / 86400 )) days
}
```

Does being on the site make this content open source and if yes what is the license of it ?
In this case this is an answer but I ask myself the same for question.

Comment: It could be an interesting question, what is with the license of the code which is not own work, but included from external sources, for example for illustration/demonstration purposes. Brrr.....

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As the footer and various other places indicate, user contributions are licensed [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). There was an attempt to have code snippets be licensed using the MIT license, but it didn't pan out. <strike>[A New Code License: The MIT, this time with Attribution Required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272956/270345)</strike>

Comment: Nice ! I never read the footer :D

Comment: Also, users are free to grant more permissions explicitly. Some do on a regular basis. Others don't think about it but might should you ask them.

Comment: In addition there is fair use: If code is in a manual, or instructional book (such as this site), then most jurisdictions will see the use of small snippets as fair-use. For example if your example was called dateDifferenceInDays, then the implementation is possibly the only way to do it in a shell script. Or after leaning how to do an `if`, then every-time you do an `if`, it will necessarily be a copy, as there is only one way to do it. This is not an infringement of copy-right. Who owns the copy-right on `if` (no body).

Comment: if the code is non-trivial, note that BY-SA 3.0 can be included in BY-SA 4.0 which can be included in GPL 3.0 or later

Comment: @d3vid while 3.0 is compatible with 4.0 (and all future versions), I don't think that means you can use 3.0-licensed code as if  it were licensed with 4.0

Comment: I believe you can include it in an adapted work: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/2213 and https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/4005